# Certain Nerd Fonts does not display properly

Tags: neovim, font, iterm2, alacritty

On my Mac (M1), I am not able to get the symbols display properly with all Nerd Fonts *excepting* one

I have installed Nerd Fonts as described in the documentation. Typically I use homebrew or have sometimes unzipped the fonts and moved them to ~/Library/Fonts

The only Nerd Font that displays icons that comes in very handy especially with nvim using LaTeX is: MesloLGS NF. I've tried Roboto Mono Nerd Font, SauceCodePro Nerd Font, FiraMono Nerd Font, JetBrainsMono Nerd Font, to name a few. I've tried this on a variety of terminals: iterm2, Alacritty, Kitty. I recall MesloLGS NF was installed with powerlevel10k theme for zsh

All help appreciated